# Neo4j nodes without relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two nodes.

How do I express the pattern "nodes without relationships"? Cannot find it in official doc!

A [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRgrw.png) to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE NOT (n)--() 
RETURN n;
```